# D3.js gives the wrong number of ticks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, d3.js

I specify that I want 3 ticks, but I get 4 in d3 js

I have these values on the y axis `[2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6]`

```
svg
  .select(`[data-labels-y]`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale).ticks(3).tickPadding(4))`
```

I expect `[0, 3, 6] - min, middle, max`
I get `[0, 2, 4, 6]`

This is strange, I specifically specify the number of ticks and it is 3

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you have a question or not, but [per the documentation](https://d3js.org/d3-scale/linear#linear_ticks), "The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the domain". The objective is to generate points that tick marks that fit nicely for a broad range of graphs.

If you wish to specify exact tick marks, simply use `.tickValues`, rather than `.ticks`. For example:

```js
let div = d3.select('#ax');

let w = 400;
let h = 80;
let svg = div.append('svg')
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("overflow", "visible")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, w, h]);

let [xmin, xmax] = [-0.4, 6.4];
let x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([xmin, xmax]).range([0, w]);

// Draw the axis
let axis = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${h / 2})`)
  .call(
    d3.axisBottom(x_scale)
      .tickValues([0, 3, 6])
      .tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
      .tickSizeOuter(0)
  );
```

```html
<div id="ax"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```